# manage cyclic queue based data pipelines

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue, python-asyncio

### Linear acyclic pipeline

I created a data pipeline based on this [design pattern](https://gist.github.com/dewaldabrie/0d63881e9d0341762092745518fcc622#file-async_queued_pipeline-py)

```
to_read  > |Extractor| > to_transform > |Transformer| > to_load > |Loader|
queue                    queue                          queue
```

In a nutshell, here is a `PipelineStage` (from which `Extractor`, `Transformer` and `Loader` inherit)

```py
class PipelineStage(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, input_q: Queue, target_qs: list, worker_nb: int = 1) -> None:
        self.input_q = input_q
        self.target_qs = target_qs
        self.tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(self._perform_tasks(i), name=f"{self.stage_name}-{i}") for i in range(worker_nb)
        ]

    @abstractmethod
    async def job(self, item, worker_id: int):
        pass

    async def _send_objects_to_target_queues(self, outp: Any):
        for target_q in self.target_qs:
            await target_q.put(outp)

    # the function that wrap a public `job` method of each pipeline stage
    async def _perform_tasks(self, worker_id: int):
        logger.info("%s [%s]: initialized", self.stage_name, worker_id)
        while True:
            item = await self.input_q.get()
            try:
                out = await self.job(item, worker_id)
                await self._send_objects_to_target_queues(out)
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.error("something")
            self.input_q.task_done()
```

Each pipeline stage just need to implement `job`

```
class Transformer(PipelineStage): 
    async def job(self, df: DataFrame, worker_id: int):
        df['some_column'] = "whatever"
        return df
```

the main function just need for all queues to reach their end while **extractor**, **transformer**, **loader** execute `_perform_tasks` in the background

```py
to_read = asyncio.Queue()
to_transform = asyncio.Queue()
to_load = asyncio.Queue()

extractor = Extractor.factory(conf, to_read, [to_transform], worker_nb=conf.get_int("source.workers"))
transformer = Transformer(conf, to_transform, [to_load], worker_nb=conf.get_int("transformations.workers"))
loader = ElasticLoader(conf, to_load, [], worker_nb=conf.get_int("destination.workers"))

await to_read.join()
await to_transform.join()
await to_load.join()
```

So far so good

### Cyclic data pipeline

What if I wanted some of my pipeline stages (say my `Transformer`) to be able to populate the `to_read` queue (i.e. some kind of dynamic job)

```
   |------------------------------------------------|
   v                                                |
to_read  > |Extractor| > to_transform > |Transformer| > to_load > |Loader|
queue                    queue                          queue
```

In this case, it does not make sense to `await .join()` these queues linearly. The program works but never ends.

I need simple way to wait for all queues to be empty, **no matter the order** (`to_read` might be empty before the `Transformer` could write on it). How would you handle it?

Comment: Could you add more code examples and tell what you expected and what is wrong there?

Comment: just did. Is it clearer?

Comment: Ok, and what do `Extractor`, `Transformer` and `ElasticLoader` classes do?

Comment: they execute `_perform_tasks` until the end of times :-)

Comment: Please also say where is the `self.job` defined?

Comment: You're trying to run three `while True` concurrently but one is enough to lock the concurrent tasks. Try to use [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan : at program initialization most of the items to be processed are *not here* and not known. I fail to understand how to transpose [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) to my case

Comment: You need [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example) example